# Language condition with Php if... elseif

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, multilingual

I would like to modify a core component of Joomla by setting up a condition based on the language the website is displaying. My code changes don't seem to work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
?>

<div class="Home"> 
<?php if ($lang->language == 'en-US') : ?>Home:
<?php elseif ($lang->language = 'fr-fr') : ?>Accueil :
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this:

```
<div class="Home"> 
<?php
  $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
  $result = $lang->getTag();
  if ($result=="fr-FR") { 
      echo 'Accueil: ';
  } 
  else { 
      echo 'Home: ';
  }
?> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Lodder this task should be done wholly through language constants and all-caps placeholders, right? I dont quite know the correct terminology.  Might you provide a best-practice answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa This is what I personally use and can't think of another approach. If you know of one, please feel free to submit another answer